# How to use /fill to fill tilled dirt?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to fill large areas of land with tilled dirt on one of my worlds. (Creative Mode) I am making a giant farm. I've been using the command /fill to put the dirt down, but is there any way to fill it already tilled? It would save me much time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. You can substitute `dirt` in whatever commands you are using for  `farmland`.

---

If you want to fill with farmland that is already watered use `farmland[moisture=7]`. (Credit @[lolad](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/210902/lolad)) Note: this will not prevent the farmland from drying out and reverting to dirt if not near a water source.

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future wanting moisturised farmland, you can use `farmland[moisture=7]` instead

Comment: Thanks, I edited my post to include that.